# Color of usb ports

Tags: usb, usb-3, dell-latitude, usb-2, usb-c

I just received a Dell laptop which should have 3x USB 3.0 ports, but every USB-port was black (2.0) as I usually thought... After some research i discovered that the way to identify the port is by the initials ("sss"=2.0, & "ss"=3.0), this kinda irritated me because the color way seems to be the dominating choice... So first of all... Is it only Dell who does this? And why? The color code is such a good system...

Answer (score 0):

Unique to manufacturer. Lenovo uses Yellow to indicate Always On. All Lenovo laptops I have used have the same speed USB for a given mode. If Dell is providing different speed types in the same model, it is unique to them how they label the ports.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question... Look inside your usb port... The color of the 'docking' part,. I have never seen a yellow nithter  I'm not talking about any lights...

Comment: Manufacturers use different colours of plastic on the ports (not lights) and that method is not common among manufacturers

Comment: The speed of the given model etc... Ain't displayed on the port or USB stick, other then which USB version it is... USB 1.0 was white.. 2.0 was black, 3.0 was blue and 3.1 was red... I think the problem is over when every device use USB-C but until that time i think there should be a unified identifier for the different versions

Comment: As noted the method you describe is not standard in any way

Comment: So you say that if you go buy a USB 3.0 USB stick, the color of the 'male' part has nothing to do with the version?

Comment: I will suggest u take a look at this Google search.. it's from the photo section: https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+3.0&client=ms-unknown&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCmLKsmt7lAhUPbFAKHae6CdoQ_AUoAXoECA0QAQ&biw=455&bih=823

Comment: USB sticks have no standard colour code and USB 3 is downward compatible so that USB 2 sticks are interchangeable in USB 3 ports

Comment: Yes I know that, but you still identify a USB 3.0 by the blue color in my experience, I don't know where you are from, and I don't disagree with you.. in some way.. you are right there aren't a written standard for the color, BUT there should be in my mind

Comment: Computers we use: Workstations and Servers do not color USB ports in any standard way. I recall seeing some blue USB ports some time back but those computers are now gone

Comment: I'm not familiar with servers so I can't talk about that, and I use 'some kind' of old hardware properly 3-4 year old stuff... But I still recon new computers both stationary and laptops with colored port... Lately the red for 3.1... I don't know where you get your knowledge from but I disagree with your answer... Go search on a new acer gaming rig... Besides the USB-c... Look at the colors...

Comment: We only use commercial workstations and computers. Acer is a consumer manufacturer and they may do things differently. For sure, however, there is not any standard, maybe just some commonality here and there.

Comment: Okay now I think we are on the same page, there's a huge difference between commercial and consumer.. and it's there I misunderstood you... Thanks for your answers and time! Have a nice weekend 

Comment: There is a colorcoding standard, but it is not a requirement. I have an Intel NUC with blue (usb 3.0 and yellow) usb 3.0 always on/charging ports.